# How to wrap SVG elements into the svg element?

Tags: svg

My SVG graph is going out of the window and there are no scroll bars.

That is because the svg element is the size of the window, and not the size of the actual svg stuff.

Is it possible to set some property on the svg element so it wraps the content (like a g element) ?

Comment: With "wrap the content" do you mean automatic layout of some kind? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ['viewBox' attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) on the root svg element so that it contains your svg fully, e.g:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10020 30">
    <line x1="10" x2="10000" y1="10" y2="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#1c94c4" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

But maybe you wanted scrollbars? In that case you can set the CSS width (or height) to something suitable, e.g:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width:10020px; height: 32px">
    <line x1="10" x2="10000" y1="10" y2="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#1c94c4" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wandered if there was a way without setting manually the width and height, so it would adjust automatically to the inner elements ?